# AngularJS - Unit Testing directives with external templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I am using the npm module `karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor` to do this.

My spec file is:

```
describe('Directive: aGreatEye (external)', function() {
    var elm, scope;

    beforeEach(module('my-thing.template.html'));
    beforeEach(module('templates'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {

        elm = angular.element('<a-great-eye></a-great-eye>');
        scope = $rootScope;
        $compile(elm)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should do first directive unit test properly', function() {
        // assertions here
    });
});
```

and yet my error is `Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module my-thing.template.html due to:
    Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'my-thing.template.html' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

Despite the url being correct from where the `basePath` of the `karma.config.js` file is.

Here is my **karma.config.js** file:

```
module.exports = function (config) {

    // VIEW ONLINE AT: MAIN_ROOT/tests/jasmineReport/
    // You can either run via WebStorm or go online to do tests

    config.set({
        basePath: '.',
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        files: [
            // Vendor Files
            'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
            'bower_components/angular-filter/dist/angular-filter.js',
            'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
            'bower_components/lodash/lodash.min.js',

            // App-Specific Files
            'app/index.js',
            'app/common/models/*.js',
            'app/common/directives/*.js',
            'app/common/filters/*.js',
            'app/main/main.js',

            // App-Specific HTML Templates
            '*.html',
            '*.html.ext',

            // Test-Specific Files
            'tests/mock/**/*.js'
        ],
        exclude: [],
        preprocessors: {

            // HTML to JavaScript Preprocessors for
            // AngularJS Template Directives
            '*.html': ['ng-html2js']

        },
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        singleRun: true,
        concurrency: Infinity,

        // NgHTML 2 JS Pre-Processor - OPTIONS
        ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
            stripPrefix: 'public/',
            stripSuffix: '.ext',
            prependPrefix: 'served/',
            moduleName: "templates"
        }
    })
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why don't you inject the template with a mock? I never used ngHtml2JsPreprocessor, I can understand that this should be done by that, but it seems to me overcomplicated...

Comment: Can you point me to the right direction? I tried search the google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these are my test for my directive, they test if the template is called correctly and elaborated correctly:

```
'use strict';

/**
* @author Gianmarco Laggia
* 
* Test suite for menu directive
*/
describe('Menu Widget Directive Rendering', function () {

    beforeEach(module('myModule'));

    var compile, mockBackend, rootScope;

    // Step 1 - Get the $compile service injected into our test
    beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $httpBackend, $rootScope) {
        compile = $compile;
        mockBackend = $httpBackend;
        rootScope = $rootScope;
    }));


    it('should render HTML based on scope correctly', function () {
        var scope = rootScope.$new();

        mockBackend.expectGET('views/directives/menu.html').respond(
            '<div class="menu">' +
            '<ul>' +
            '<li><a href="#/" class="waves-effect waves-light">HOME</a></li>' +
            '<li><a href="#/activities" class="waves-effect waves-light">ATTIVIT</a></li>' +
            '<li><a href="#/people" class="waves-effect waves-light">PERSONE</a></li>' +
            '<li><a href="#/locations" class="waves-effect waves-light">LUOGHI</a></li>' +
            '<div class="clear-both"></div>' +
            '</ul>' +
            '</div>');

        //Step 4
        var element = compile('<menu></menu>')(scope);

        //Step 5
        scope.$digest();
        mockBackend.flush();

        //Step 6
        expect(element.html()).toEqual(
            '<div class="menu">' +
            '<ul>' +
            '<li><a href="#/" class="waves-effect waves-light">HOME</a></li>' +
            '<li><a href="#/activities" class="waves-effect waves-light">ATTIVIT</a></li>' +
            '<li><a href="#/people" class="waves-effect waves-light">PERSONE</a></li>' +
            '<li><a href="#/locations" class="waves-effect waves-light">LUOGHI</a></li>' +
            '<div class="clear-both"></div>' +
            '</ul>' +
            '</div>'
        );
        mockBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    });

    it('should not render HTML is used not as element 1', function () {
        //Step 2 - Set up our directive instance HTML
        var scope = rootScope.$new();

        //Step 4
        var element = compile('<div menu></div>')(scope);

        //Step 5
        scope.$digest();

        //Step 6
        expect(element.html()).toEqual('');
        mockBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    it('should not render HTML is used not as element 2', function () {
        //Step 2 - Set up our directive instance HTML
        var scope = rootScope.$new();

        //Step 4
        var element = compile('<div class="menu"></div>')(scope);

        //Step 5
        scope.$digest();

        //Step 6
        expect(element.html()).toEqual('');
        mockBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    it('should not render HTML is used not as element 3', function () {
        //Step 2 - Set up our directive instance HTML
        var scope = rootScope.$new();

        //Step 4
        var element = compile('<!-- directive: menu -->')(scope);

        //Step 5
        scope.$digest();

        //Step 6
        expect(element.html()).toBeUndefined();
        mockBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });
});
```

This test that the directive is called only with `<menu></menu>` due to its restriction

```
/**
* @author Gianmarco Laggia
*
* Menu directive, used to handle a menu based on the actual $location.path
*/
angular.module('myModule')
    .directive('menu', ['Page', function (Page) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: true,
            templateUrl: 'views/directives/menu.html',
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.isCurrentPage = function (page) {
                    return Page.getActualPage() == page;
                };
            }
        };
}]);
```

Comment: The only thing I have a problem with is that you need to add your own response with your own data.. I with to grab the template instead of making your own response. But thank you.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean

Comment: In the line `mockBackend.expectGET('views/directives/menu.html').respond(` you are telling the code what to get back as data when I really want the template.html to be inserted in there

Comment: in my opinion it's a bad practis to have unit tests that depends on external resources. The thing is that is unnecessary to pass the directive the actual file, the reason is that if that file change you will never be able to assert on it (the assertion is hardcoded)

Comment: I am not sure I follow. I mean. I think I got it but the last part got to me. So are you saying that I should unit test my directives with inline templates?

Comment: I am not sure, that it's good practice to test for a hardcoded response. Don't you actually want to test the real template? What IF the template changes? Then the test should fail, as the template does not follow the specification of the test.

Comment: That is an End To End test, then. This is unit test, to test the .directive() method.